# Unclear crash in com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, crash-reports

Just got very unclear (at least to me) memory crash

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x4086ec0000000000

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority
0  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x000000019587d550 OSAtomicDequeue + 16
1  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x000000019583bfb4 nano_pressure_relief + 400
2  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x000000019583a27c malloc_zone_pressure_relief + 208
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001956ec3e0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
```

Other threads seems to do nothing interesting, most of them do nothing, but UI probably processed something however after learning the stacktrace I have no idea what was happening.

```
Thread : com.apple.main-thread
0  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000188c93330 __CFStringHash + 288
1  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000188bbecb4 CFBasicHashFindBucket + 1092
2  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000188bbe830 CFDictionaryGetValue + 144
3  UIKit                          0x000000018bb9d904 -[UIApplication _isSpringBoard] + 48
4  UIKit                          0x000000018bb9d7b8 -[UIDevice setOrientation:animated:] + 80
5  UIKit                          0x000000018bb9cb18 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 752
6  UIKit                          0x000000018bb9c720 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 104
7  UIKit                          0x000000018bc0a0b0 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 712
8  GraphicsServices               0x000000018e5a9128 _PurpleEventCallback + 676
9  GraphicsServices               0x000000018e5a8c54 PurpleEventCallback + 48
10 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000188c86fc8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
11 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000188c86f28 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 444
12 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000188c8514c __CFRunLoopRun + 1620
13 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000188bc5b38 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
14 GraphicsServices               0x000000018e5a7830 GSEventRunModal + 168
15 UIKit                          0x000000018bc040e8 UIApplicationMain + 1156
16 SalesBoard4                    0x0000000100168644 main (main.m:16)
17 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000195707aa0 start + 4
```

Device iPad Air, iOS version 7.0.4

Please, if you know what it is or, at least, know how to deal with that, share your knowledge.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> "Memory overcommitment is a concept in virtualization that covers the assignment of more memory to virtual computing devices than the physical machine they are hosted on actually has."

Source: Wikipedia

SO you can see it a memory issue. Check if you are using a lot memory somewhere.

Comment: Thank you! This is the first thing I thought about, but the app never grows more that 150MB in RAM. And this is iPad Air. Does it mean, if the user has a bunch of apps in the background and then my apps asks for its  small part of 150MB it will be killed because others, that probably were moved in foreground two days ago, and are still there?

Comment: It might be a reason. I've someone encountered this error wile loading a large image. Though I never faced this error.

Comment: But why iOS kills the app this way, just pointing to somewhere (some invalid address)?